# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable does not contain a method named 'Execute'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm

I got the error when I add a row to an Azure storage table using AzureRm (version 1.0.0.23) module in PowerShell. In the Microsoft document, the method "Execute" is existed. Below is the code I used to add a row. If there are some parameters missing?

```
Add-StorageTableRow -table $storageTable `
 -partitionKey "201901" `
 -rowKey (xxxx) `
```

Comment: I have changed the AzureRmStorageTable module several versions, but it still can not works. Same error as version 1.0.0.23

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the Az module from Powershell and replaced all Az commands with those exported from the AzureRm module, then it works fine. Maybe using the Az and AzureRm module at the same time is really a bad idea.